# C# Support for Simultaneous and Editable Languages

Tags: c#

I'm currently developing an application that needs the hability to simultaneously show messages in 2 different languages. 
(Eg:. User salutation would result in the following message to appear at the display:
"Welcome to my app"
"Bienvenue sur mon application")

Disregarding character encoding issues, what are your suggestions regarding implementation of this feature?

I am thinking about putting all the messages in a database and select the 2 different versions of the message for the available languages.

One more caveat. Messages can be changed by user.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are on the right path then. You simply need a content holder in the database, a content editor in your application, and then a query to select content for a specific resource name.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a messages table with [locale id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h88fahh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a field. You then identify the locale using local settings, and identify the message with an enum:

```
var message = GetMessage(localeId, Messages.Welcome);
```

Keep in mind that language is probably not the only thing that you'll have to keep in mind...dates, currency, all of that localization fun.